# Nested JSON to data table with LINQ and asp.net c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to get the below nested json to the datatable.I was able to deserialize this but I can't get this to table. I have tried wit classes but that doesn't parse. Also, I have looked for similar posts or json sequence but couldn't find a fix.

```
{
"firstName": "JANICE",
"middleName": "F",
"lastName": "MORANZ",
"npi": "1295821098",
"nationalProviderIdentifierType": "1",
"firstApprovedDate": "2012-03-19T04:00:00.000Z",
"yearsInMedicare": 5,
"pecosEnrollmentDate": 2012,
"newlyEnrolled": false,
"organizations": [
    {
        "prvdrOrgName": "SOUTHWEST INTEGRATIVE HEALTH CENTER, LLC",
        "addressLineOne": "SOUTHWEST INTEGRATIVE HEALTH CENTER LLC",
        "addressLineTwo": "5310 HOMESTEAD RD NE BLDG 400",
        "city": "ALBUQUERQUE",
        "zip": "87110",
        "state": "NM",
        "individualScenario": {
            "aggregationLevel": 2,
            "mipsEligibleSwitch": true,
            "lowVolumeSwitch": true,
            "lowVolumeStatusReasons": [
                {
                    "lowVolStusRsnCd": "CHRG",
                    "lowVolStusRsnDesc": "Clinicianâ€™s Part B expenditures"
                }
            ]
        },
        "groupScenario": {
            "aggregationLevel": 1,
            "lowVolumeSwitch": false,
            "lowVolumeStatusReasons": []
        }
    }
],
"specialty": {
    "specialtyDescription": "Dermatology",
    "categoryReference": "Physicians",
    "typeDescription": "Doctor of Medicine"
}
}
```

Here's my code. I have posted the method here. Please let me know where am I stuck.All the Root objects pass but the array organizations doesn't pass through the loop

```
public DataTable GetDataTableFromJsonString(string json)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {


            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
    new DataColumn("firstName")
    ,new DataColumn("middleName")
    ,new DataColumn("lastName")
    ,new DataColumn("npi")
    ,new DataColumn("nationalProviderIdentifierType")
    //,new DataColumn("state")
    ,new DataColumn("firstApprovedDate")
    ,new DataColumn("yearsInMedicare")
    ,new DataColumn("pecosEnrollmentDate")
    ,new DataColumn("newlyEnrolled") 
    ,new DataColumn("organizations")
    ,new DataColumn("specialty")
    ,new DataColumn("prvdrOrgName")
    ,new DataColumn("addressLineOne")
    ,new DataColumn("addressLineTwo")
    ,new DataColumn("zip")
    ,new DataColumn("state")
    ,new DataColumn("individualScenario")});
            var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(json);
            JToken organizations;
            string firstName = string.Empty;
            string middleName = string.Empty;
            string lastName = string.Empty;
            string npi1 = string.Empty;
            string nationalProviderIdentifierType = string.Empty;
           // string state = string.Empty;
            string firstApprovedDate = string.Empty;
            string yearsInMedicare = string.Empty;
            string pecosEnrollmentDate = string.Empty;
            string newlyEnrolled = string.Empty;
            string organizations1 = string.Empty;
            string specialty = string.Empty;
            string prvdrOrgName = string.Empty;
            string addressLineOne = string.Empty;
            string addressLineTwo = string.Empty;
            string city = string.Empty;
            string zip = string.Empty;
            string state = string.Empty;
            string individualScenario = string.Empty;
            string lowVolumeStatusReasons = string.Empty;
            string lowVolumeStatusReasons1 = string.Empty;
            string npi = String.Empty;




            // string firstName = string.Empty;
            List<JToken> results = jsonLinq.Children().ToList();
            foreach (JProperty item in results)
            {
                item.CreateReader();
                //if (item.Name == "data")
                //{
                organizations = item.Value;
                foreach (JObject jProp in organizations.Children().ToList())
                    {
                        organizations = jProp["organizations"].ToString();
                        foreach (JProperty jitem in jProp["organizations"].Children().ToList())
                        {
                            if (jitem.Name == "firstName")
                            {
                                firstName = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }

                            if (jitem.Name == "middleName")
                            {
                                middleName = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "lastName")
                            {
                                lastName = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "npi")
                            {
                                npi = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "nationalProviderIdentifierType")
                            {
                                nationalProviderIdentifierType = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "firstApprovedDate")
                            {
                                firstApprovedDate = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "yearsInMedicare")
                            {
                                yearsInMedicare = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "pecosEnrollmentDate")
                            {
                                pecosEnrollmentDate = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "newlyEnrolled")
                            {
                                newlyEnrolled = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            //if (jitem.Name == "organizations")
                            //{
                            //    organizations = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            //}

                            if (jitem.Name == "organizations")
                            {
                                if (jitem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                                {
                                    JArray items = (JArray)jitem.Value;
                                    prvdrOrgName = items[0].SelectToken("value").ToString();
                                }
                                if (jitem.Name == "specialty")
                                {
                                    specialty = jitem.Value.ToString();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        foreach (JProperty jitem in jProp["organizations"].Children().ToList())
                        {
                            if (jitem.Name == "prvdrOrgName")
                            {
                                prvdrOrgName = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }

                            if (jitem.Name == "addressLineOne")
                            {
                                addressLineOne = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }

                            if (jitem.Name == "addressLineTwo")
                            {
                                addressLineTwo = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "city")
                            {
                                city = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "zip")
                            {
                                zip = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "state")
                            {
                                state = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "individualScenario")
                            {
                                individualScenario = jitem.Value.ToString();
                            }

                            if (jitem.Name == "lowVolumeStatusReasons")
                            {
                                if (jitem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                                {
                                    JArray items = (JArray)jitem.Value;
                                    lowVolumeStatusReasons = items[0].SelectToken("value").ToString();
                                }
                            }
                            if (jitem.Name == "lowVolumeStatusReasons")
                            {
                                if (jitem.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                                {
                                    JArray items = (JArray)jitem.Value;
                                    lowVolumeStatusReasons1 = items[0].SelectToken("value").ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(firstName, middleName, lastName, npi1, nationalProviderIdentifierType, firstApprovedDate, yearsInMedicare, pecosEnrollmentDate, newlyEnrolled, organizations, prvdrOrgName, addressLineOne, addressLineTwo, city, zip, state, individualScenario);
                //}
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this lengthy code, user newtonsoft json library http://www.newtonsoft.com/json for .NET. Add it from nuget package manager in your solution.

using that your code should look like.

```
 public DataTable DerializeDataTable(String jsonString)
{

    var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried this in the very beginning. My code is using the library you mentioned. I am not down voting you. Please read the question clearly before you post your answer.

Comment: you haven't clearly mentioned that you have tried JSON.NET, instead you have used words "Also, I have looked for similar posts or json sequence but couldn't find a fix."